# Downcasting versus upcasting within class hierarchy

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I have the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Parent p = new Child();
    Child c = null;
    Grandchild g = null;


    p = c; // upcast
    c = (Child) p; // downcast
    c = (Grandchild) p; // downcast ?

}
```

Where `Grandchild` is a sub of `Child` and `Child` is a sub of `Parent`.

I know that `p=c` is an upcast and that `c = (Child) p;` is a legal downcast, up to this point. Now, my question is, what is `c = (Grandchild) p;`?
I'm confused as to how we can downcast `p` all the way down to `Grandchild`. However, if `c` is of type Child, the wouldn't `c = (Grandchild) p;` be considered an upcast if the `Grandchild` class is a subtype of `Child`?

Comment: It will compile without errors but will throw an exception during runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c = (Grandchild) p;` will result in a `ClassCastException` if `p` was instantiated to `Child` (as in your example). So, it is neither a cast or a downcast. Example :

```
Parent p = new Child();
GrandChild g;
g = (GrandChild)p;
```

will result in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: test.Child cannot be cast to test.GrandChild
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:18)
Java Result: 1
```

To make it valid, you have to instantiate `p` as a `GrandChild` :

```
Parent p = new GrandChild();
GrandChild g;
g = (GrandChild)p;
```